# Lake Tahoe or Yosemite in Jan?

Tags: usa, california

My parents and grandma are visiting the US in the coming January. I've planned around 10 days in California: 2.5 days in San Fransisco, 2.5 days in Los Angeles, and the rest 5 days along the famous Highway 1.

I was told that 5 days on Highway 1 is really unnecessarily long, so I am considering adding one more destination. I've narrowed my options down to Lake Tahoe or Yosemite. Which is more suitable (in terms of scenery, convinience of driving, etc.) for winter visits?

P.S.: We will be driving a RV, if this matters.

Comment: What do you mean by "more suitable"? In what regard?

Comment: @Fiksdal Sorry for being unclear. Question updated.

Comment: That helps a bit, thanks. However I'd advise you to be even more specific. Perhaps add a few sentences explaining what sort of experience you are looking for. This question has now received two close-votes as primarily opinion based, and the more specific you are the more likely you are to ward off future close-votes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For either Tahoe or Yosemite, you could get caught in a snowstorm with relatively little warning, that might require chains or even closure of the road. Both are about 4 hours from San Francisco, so you are adding an entire day of driving. I would suggest neither, and instead going either to the Wine Country north of San Francisco (Napa and Sonoma valleys, also Point Reyes National Seashore), or San Diego. Highway 1 is two days. And it is not easy to drive in an RV.

Comment: Many thanks for the advice! Indeed, RV getting caught in the snowstorm will be disastrous. The places you suggested are all nearby besides Highway 1. Sounds much more doable and safer from the snowstorms! SD definitely sounds attractive in winter!